# How to implement momentum zooming

Tags: javascript

I would like to implement zooming like is done on [this site](https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/) (click the menu -> demo) or [this site](https://app.flowhub.io/#project/138d806e-2b18-4cb5-961b-d7148258deeb/d13c397f-02e0-4d96-859c-abfe268d8bad). As you can see you can zoom in and out with momentum.

So, my question was, how is that possible. My initial though was something like this

```
<main>
    <section class="scrolling"></section>

   <section class="overlay">
       <button class="demo">Hello</button>
   </section>
```

A `.scrolling` layer with an invisible scrollbar. The overlay positioned `fixed` on top of the `.scolling` layer with `pointer-events: none`

```
.scrolling {
    height: 1000vh;
    position: relative;
}

.overlay {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
 }
```

and a bit of js

```
main.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    const scale = .... magic magic ....
    overlay.style.transform = 'scale(...)';
});
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/htk6z9m2/5/)

As you can see in the demo if you scroll the overlay has momentum-zoom. 
But there is one huge problem with my demo

- the button is not clickabe
- the button doesn't show a mouse-pointer if you move over it

Any suggestions what I can do to fix the above issues ?
And are there libraries that support this feature? For example, I found [Impetus.js](https://chrisbateman.github.io/impetus/) but it doesn't seem to do momentum based on the scrolling gesture.